# Create a Dictionary by ignoring repeating keys

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have this Dictionary:

`var Dict = Dictionary<Obj, Value>`

And I want to create a new one that is:

`var Dict2 = Dictionary<Obj.ParentId, Value>`

However, there might be objects that have the same `ParentId`, so that would be a problem when creating a new Dictionary. Any two entries with the same `ParentId` will have the same Value, so I only care to keep one of the entries. Is there a way to easily do this either through LINQ?

Comment: Which of the entries do you want to keep? The first? By some criteria?

Comment: Any would be fine, since they would be identical

Comment: What are the types of `ParentId` and `Value`? You can use [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-6.0) or you might need [`DistinctBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0).

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary automatically removes duplicate entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Linq*: query `Dict` and *materialize* result as `Dict2`

```
var Dict2 = Dict
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key.ParentId, pair => pair.Value)
   // Or group.Last().Value or some other logic
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.First().Value);
```

Or you can try looping:

```
var Dict2 = Dictionary<Obj.ParentId, Value>();

foreach (var pair in Dict)
  Dict2.TryAdd(pair.Key.ParentId, pair.Value);
```

Comment: oh, I think that TryAdd is just what I needed! Didn't know this method existed.

Comment: @Ankad The difference between these two answers is that `TryAdd` gives you the first added value, but `=` gives you the last

Comment: I'll note that if you don't mind a loop, the `foreach` is likely to be the most efficient - `GroupBy` or `Distinct` essentially create a `HashSet`  or a `LookUp` (a dictionary that supports multiple values for a key) so you are doing double work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is probably imperatively using a loop. In this approach, the last one wins - but, as you say, this shouldn't matter in your case:

```cs
var dict2 = new Dictionary<Obj.ParentId, Value>();

foreach (var (key, value) in dict1)
{
    dict2[key.ParentId] = value;
}
```

You could also do this using LINQ, but it's probably less performant given it has to do the 'distinct' part first:

```cs
var dict2 = dict1
    .DistinctBy(x => x.Key.ParentId)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ParentId, x => x.Value);
```